# Python - Scraping with BeautifulSoup not showing all rows

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a novice with BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to scrape the "Season Stats" table from [ESPN Fantasy Basketball Standings](http://games.espn.com/fba/standings?leagueId=20960&seasonId=2017), but not all rows are returned. After some research, I thought that it might be a problem with html.parser, so I used lxml. I got the same results. If anyone could tell me how to get ALL team names, I would appreciate it.

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://games.espn.com/fba/standings?leagueId=20960&seasonId=2017"),'html.parser')
tableStats = soup.find("table", {"class" : "tableBody"})
for row in tableStats.findAll('tr')[2:]:
    col = row.findAll('td')

    try:
        name = col[0].a.string.strip()
        print(name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Output (as you can see, only a few team names are displayed):

`Le Tuc Grizzlies
Peyton Ravens
Heaven Vultures
Versailles Golden Bears
Baltimore Corto's
La Murette Scavengers
XO Gayfishes`

Comment: You seem to be taking the wrong table. Why not take the total ranking section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be taking the wrong `table` altogether. Instead of running a `find()` for the `<table>` tag, you could use a `findAll()` instead and look for the correct table having the entire ranking. Also I note the stats table has a special table `id` called `statsTable`. It's a good idea to look for this `id` instead of the `class` as it's unique to an HTML file.

Have a look at the comments in the following code for more guidelines,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
# Note, I'm using requests here as it's a superior library
text = requests.get("http://games.espn.com/fba/standings?leagueId=20960&seasonId=2017").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,'html.parser')
# searching by id, always a better option when available
tableStats = soup.find("table", {"id" : "statsTable"})
for row in tableStats.findAll('tr')[3:]:
    col = row.findAll('td')
    try:
        # This fetches all the text in the tag stripped off all the HTML
        name = col[1].get_text()
        print(name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to parse `id="statsTable"`, which contains all teams, i.e.:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://games.espn.com/fba/standings?leagueId=20960&seasonId=2017"),'html.parser')
tableStats = soup.find('table', id="statsTable")
for row in tableStats.findAll('a', href=True):
    print row.text
```